# Can't get embedded UIViewController to rotate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uikit

My app was rotating in landscape before I introduced my UINavigationController.  Now it seems like the UINavigationController rotates, but the viewcontroller doesn't.  I've read through all the documentation over, and over and I can't figure this out.

Here is my code in appDelegate

```
    // UINAVIGATIONCONTROLLER
    let ksNavigationController = KSNavigationController()
    // UIVIEWCONTROLLER
    let gameViewController = GameViewController()

    ksNavigationController.pushViewController(gameViewController, animated: false)
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = ksNavigationController
```

I read in apple's documentation:

Beginning with iOS 6, only the topmost view controller (alongside the UIApplication object) participates in deciding whether to rotate in response to a change of the device's orientation. More often than not, the view controller displaying your content is a child of UINavigationController, UITabBarController, or a custom container view controller. You may find yourself needing to subclass a container view controller in order to modify the values returned by its supportedInterfaceOrientations and shouldAutorotate methods

so i've done that in my UINavigationController subclass

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape.rawValue)
}
```

it doesn't work.  My UIViewController wont rotate.  Can I please get some help in the form of code?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write a code, Please make sure that in the application target->General tab -> Deployment Info, you checked the Landscape left and Landscape right options as well along with the Portrait option against the Device Orientation field.

Comment: Landscape left and right is checked. I don't want to support portrait orientation

Comment: Then uncheck the Portrait and UpsideDown options, check only the Landscape Right and Landscape Left options, It just works fine for me.

Comment: thats what i have.. only landscape left and right.  There must be something else preventing the viewcontroller from rotating

Comment: You must be using storyboard, ain't you?

Comment: ahh, i had to uncheck "is initial view controller" from my GameViewController in storyboard.  thanks for the help!